# How can I create multiple csv files for different tables from the same sheet in google sheets

Tags: csv, google-sheets, export-to-csv

My task is to create 3-4 csv files from one google sheet that has inside 3-4 tables with different data. So I need to create 3-4 csv files for each table.

I try to create a csv file but it selects all the sheets and combines them into one csv file!

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your tables are in a single sheet, **copy each one of them to a separate new sheet and download them independently**.

[image]

---

- You can then delete the newly created sheets.

Comment: this is a good idea, thank you!